# IHTMLTxtRange.pasteHTML doesn't replace old HTML

Tags: c#, mshtml

I'm writing a simple HTML WYSIWYG editor using Microsoft's mshtml. One of the features should be selecting a header type (e.g. h1, h2, h3) for a selected text. The first assignment is no problem with the following code:

```
// *doc* is my IHTMLDocument
// *tag* contains the header tag

IHTMLTxtRange range = (IHTMLTxtRange)doc.selection.createRange()
string rangeText = range.text;
IHTMLElement elem = doc.createElement(tag)
elem.innerHTML = rangeText;
range.pasteHTML(elem.outerHTML);
```

When I try to change the header, the old one doesn't get replaced though MSDN says about pasteHTML:

> Pastes HTML text into the given text
>   range, replacing any previous text and
>   HTML elements in the range.

This means if my HTML was

```
<H1>foo</H1>
```

after the first assignment, it gets

```
<H1>
<H2>asdasd</H2></H1>
```

after the second.

What am I doing wrong? Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you managed to solve this issue? I'm having the same problem. When i replace a selected anchor it gets pasted inside itself.

Comment: @nick2083 I added an answer to the question

Comment: It doesn't work because the selected range does not include the outer HTML even when you select the entire contents of the element. You can tell this by looking at `range.htmlText`, it only contains "foo". This behaviour is correct because you normally just want to replace `foo` with some other string and you wouldn't want to lose the <H1> element doing that. You need to use something like @Ahmad's trick.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried changing the last line to

```
range.pasteHTML(elem.innerHTML);
```

?
 I think the outerHTML would include the original h1 tag, and then you would paste

```
<H1><H2>asdasd</H2></H1>
```

OVER

```
<H1>foo</H1>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and solved it via

```
   string rangeText = range.text;
    IHTMLDOMNode parentNode = range.parentElement() as IHTMLDOMNode;
    if (parentNode.nodeName.Contains("H") && parentNode.nodeName.Length == 2)
    {
        parentNode.removeNode(true);
    }
    IHTMLElement elem = doc.createElement(tag);
    elem.innerHTML = rangeText; 
    range.pasteHTML(elem.outerHTML);
```

Comment: +1 but you should probably check that `range.text == range.parentElement().innerText` to make sure that the entire element has been selected before you remove the node.

Answer (score 0):

Clearing the selection will do it:

```
IHTMLTxtRange range = (IHTMLTxtRange)doc.selection.createRange();
string rangeText = range.text; 
doc.selection.clear();
IHTMLElement elem = doc.createElement(tag); 
elem.innerHTML = rangeText; 
range.pasteHTML(elem.outerHTML);
```